# LWP::UserAgent getting 204 No Content response when POST in loop with multiple file contents

Tags: perl, lwp, lwp-useragent

I need to POST content from multiple files, so I have read data from multiple files and posting in a Loop. For the first file content post I am getting 200 OK response, for the second file content I am parsing the second file content but it is showing response as 204 No content. Below is my code. Please help me to resolve this.

```
#! usr/bin/perl
require LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;

my $EX_OK = 0;
my $EX_TEMPFAIL = -1;

my $url = 'http://jeffbeck.corp.apple.com:6080/parser/post';

my $dir = $ARGV[0];
my $i = 1;

opendir DIR, $dir or die "cannot open dir $dir: $!";
my @filename = map{s/\.[^.]+$//;$_}grep {/\.eml$/} readdir DIR;
foreach $file (@filename){
    print "$file \t $dir \n";
    $filePath = "$dir/$file.eml";
    print "$filePath \n";
        #open the file as input and process that.
        open (MYFILE, $filePath) or die "Couldn't open file $filePath : $!";

        while(<MYFILE>) {
            #$mailContent = $mailContent . $_ ;
            @content = <MYFILE>;
        }
        print "###############################################\n";
    print @content;
        print "\n###############################################\n";

    close(MYFILE);

        #Getting Message Id and replacing '@' with '_'
        my $messageId='';

    foreach $mailContent (@content){

        if($mailContent =~ m/Message-id: \<(.*)\>/i) {
            $messageId  = $1;
        }
        }
        $messageId =~ s/[@]/_/gi;
        print "My message ID is : $messageId \n";
        print "My mail content is : @content \n";
        print "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n";
        #Getting mailsize to be logged.
        my $response;
        my $mailsize = (length(@content)/1024);
        my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;

        #post the same to the URL above with messageid and mailContent
        $response = $browser->post($url,
        [ 'messageId'   => $messageId,
        'mailContent' => @content,
        ]);
        print "My response $response\n";
        print $response->status_line;
        #fetch response and print output.
        if( $response->status_line =~ m{200 OK} )
        {
            print "\tResponse is Success. Code is $EX_OK & message size is $mailsize KB \n";
        }
        else
        {
            print "\tResponse is failure. Code is $EX_TEMPFAIL \n";
        }

    }
closedir DIR;
```

Comment: Use `Data::Dumper` and `print Dumper \$response;`. A server error is a server error - you may need to look in the logs there.

Comment: Also - your `map grep readdir` could probably be shortened into a single `glob`.

Comment: A 204 response is a still a successful response. If you don't expect this response check with your target script why you generate such a response.